# Grouping values in a column by a criteria and getting their mean using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have data on movies and all movies have IMDB score, however some do not have a meta critic score

Eg:

| Name | IMDB Score | Meta Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 8 | 86 |
| C | 8 | 90 |
| D | 8 | null |
| E | 8 | 91 |
| F | 7 | 66 |
| G | 3 | 44 |

I want to fill in the null  values in the meta critic score with the mean of the values of movies that have the same IMDB score
so the null value in this table should be replaced by the mean of movies B,C,E

How would I achieve this with Numpy / Pandas?

I looked up online and the closest solution I could find was averaging all the metacritic scores and replacing the null values with that Average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` + `fillna`

```
df.groupby('IMDB Score')['Meta Score'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

output:

```
0    86.0
1    90.0
2    89.0
3    91.0
4    66.0
5    44.0
Name: Meta Score, dtype: float64
```

make result to `Meta Score` column

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the columns with missing values then do a forward fill:

```
df['Meta Score'] = df.groupby(['Name','IMDB Score'])['Meta Score'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code first does the group by, then transform it by calculating mean.

```
df.groupby('IMDB Score')['Meta Score'].transform(lambda value: value.fillna(value.mean()))
```

And then output is:

```
0    86.0
1    90.0
2    89.0
3    91.0
4    66.0
5    44.0
Name: Meta Score, dtype: float64
```

you can also replace the `Meta Score` column:

```
df["Meta Score"] = df.groupby("IMDB Score")["Meta Score"].transform(
    lambda value: value.fillna(value.mean())
)
```

```
  Name  IMDB Score  Meta Score
0    B           8        86.0
1    C           8        90.0
2    D           8        89.0
3    E           8        91.0
4    F           7        66.0
5    G           3        44.0
```